# Update huge data in database

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

I have done little googling but its still abstract that if I would like to update a table in database;in that scenrio shall I use store procedure.If yes,then how does it help to gain performance in my code?

Edit:

What exactly are you trying to do?

I am supposed to update around 2000+ or 3000+  {may vary in this approx range} in a table.

What have you tried?

I had written a simple update query :

```
update table set ... where ...
```

My senior asked me to use instead a stored procedure which is a better way to do the same.And I am trying to figure it out how?

Comment: Please edit your question to answer the following questions: What exactly are you trying to do? What have you tried? With what results? How do they not match your requirements?

Comment: What is your definition of huge? Can the update be done in a one-line sql statement?

Comment: Doing something in SQL is by far the most efficient method (i.e. what you've done). If you put this in a stored procedure it is identical... if you look it's less efficient...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, stored procedures have nothing to do with Java. Stored procedures help to gain performance because they mean less communication between server and client is needed for complex tasks. Whether or not to use them depends on what you are trying to do. If you can formulate the task in one sql query, then the answer is probably: No, you won't get performance gains - as i explained before, the performance gains are only there if you need to make multiple queries in succession.

So, do you:

- update your 2000+ items with one simple query -> no stored procedure necessary
- update your 2000+ items with 2000+ queries in a loop -> yes, use a stored procedure if that means you only need to call it once for all 2000+ items

Ok, now someone else answer the question how he can create a stored procedure with Java :-P

Comment: thx!edited the same.And i am newbie in programming,sorry if some part sounds trivial to you.And its _she_

Comment: Oh, what i didnt explicitly say: the whole point of the stored procedure is that it is executed by the database server itself.